# Log bluetooth transfer activity in android

Tags: android, logging, bluetooth, transfer

Is it possible to check in Android when 2 connected devices (paired? bonded?) start transferring a file over Bluetooth?

I need to find a way how to log the time it takes for the 2 devices to transfer the file, and some specifications about the device who is being connected to.

Could anyone point me in the right direction...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of (if I understand you correctly) is the logcat output.  The logcat statements include time stamps and they include a lot of information about what is happening in Bluetooth.

If you aren't already setup to read logcat statements over debug you can grab one of the [logcat apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en) and check out all the Bluetooth debug statements coming out of the system.

Now write a program to read logcat and parse...